# As was the case with

Tags: idioms

Context:

The thing I love the most about leopard seals is that they are amazing communicators. They are full of curiosity and always seem to have an excess of bravado for the first few minutes of an encounter. Then they either leave or stick around and act like a huge dog as was the case with this beauty. < --- > I have been around wild animals all of my life and believe that I exude a calm energy and in turn, they relax. < --- >

What does 'as was the case with' mean or synonym?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Then they either leave or stick around and act like a huge dog, as this beauty did.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at our sister site, English Language Learners, https://ell.stackexchange.com/.  It may be a better fit for your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "as is/was the case [for]" is used to indicate that what has been established for the group also holds true for a particular member of the group. In the context given the behavior described as typical for leopard seals also applies to the particular leopard seal the author is referencing. It is not an exception.